# Meteor Session variables and jquery events

Tags: jquery, meteor

I have been mixing uses of Meteor Session variables / Deps.autorun and jquery .trigger / .on for reactive purposes. I am wondering, if the reactivity does not involve data displayed in the UI, is it better to use jquery events?

Is there any advantage of using one over the other such as performance, in case I start having lots of activities, timeouts, canvas rendering, etc?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, using jQuery to manipulate your DOM is really painful. When template rerenders, you lose all the manipulations you've made, unless you've placed the element in `#constant` block or did some other precautions to ensure the state is saved. Whatever method you've used for this, it will most probably be deprecated in Blaze, which thankfully should make such manipulations easier.

For now, it's better to stick with the convention and stick with reactivity for any change that involves even simple manipulation with your data.

Comment: I didn't ask the question correctly, let me update it. I am thinking about the reactive layer beneath UI. So for example, on keydown or mousedown and touchstart, jquery would trigger multiple events for changes not in the UI and the next set of changes would also use jquery events because UI is not involved yet, and then when it reaches the UI, I use Session variables. What I am wondering about is the first and second use of jquery in the non-UI logic; let say if there is a 3rd non-UI logic layer, I feel more incline to use jquery events, but seems to be okay either way.

Comment: Now I'm confused. But if it works, that's great – all the UI code is changing in Blaze anyway so it probably doesn't matter that much which method will you use now.